# Múltiplas turmas para um aluno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Tenho uma aplicação de ensino nela tenho um model para Turmas (Room) e outro para Alunos (Student).

Na minha regra de negócios cada aluno pode ser matriculado em até 3 turmas.
Para isso eu simplesmente criei 3 colunas a mais no cadastro de alunos.

1. room_1 (integer)
2. room_2 (integer)
3. room_3 (integer)

E na criação coloco o id da turma de forma manual (form select) dentro de cada coluna.

Meu problema é que:

1. sei que não é e forma correta de criar esse relacionamento.
2. Estou tendo diversos problemas na hora de gerar relatório por que preciso dar diversas voltas para consultar os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro é necessário fazer uma table N:N.

```
rails g model student_rooms student:references room:references
```

Agora, fazemos as migrações para criar as `foreign_keys`.

```
rails g migration AddStudentRoomToRooms student_room:references
rails g migration AddStudentRoomToStudents student_room:references
rails db:migrate
```

Nos models:

```
class StudentRoom
 belongs_to :student
 belongs_to :room
...

class Room
 has_many :student_rooms
 has_many :students, through: :student_rooms 
...

class Student
  has_many :student_rooms, validates_length_of :rooms, maximum: 3
  has_many :rooms, through: :student_rooms
...
```

Uma `Room` possui muitos `students` e um `Student` possui muitas `rooms`. A table `StudentRooms` serve apenas para conectar as duas tables. O que impede que um `Student` tenha mais de 3 `Rooms` é a `validates_length_of`.